# Pythonic way of accessing Django objects

Tags: python, django

Can any one suggest me the way to do these requests in pythonic way.

```
customer=Customer.objects.get(pk=pk) if (type=='pk') else Customer.objects.get(uid=uid)
```

Comment: What's not pythonic about that ?

Comment: I think someone is being caught up in buzzword fever.

Comment: The only *possible* issue I see is that there's a possibility of confusing `kwargs` with your var name, but otherwise there's nothing not standard about this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not that there's much wrong with what you have but another way you can do that is to have one reference to the `Customer.objects` manager seeing that the only thing you're doing different is within the `get` method.

For instance:

```
customer = Customer.objects
customer = customer.get(pk=pk) if (type=='pk') else customer.get(uid=uid)
```

Comment: Thanks. It is better somewhat